# My code won't work to read from a text file

Tags: vb.net

My Visual Basic code works to write to the file, but not to read from it. Reading from the file needs to be part of the splash screen, so I can't move it to the main KMFile class. Can you help me figure out what's wrong with this code?

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class SplashScreen1

    'TODO: This form can easily be set as the splash screen for the application by going to the "Application" tab
    '  of the Project Designer ("Properties" under the "Project" menu).


    Private Sub SplashScreen1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        'Set up the dialog text at runtime according to the application's assembly information.
        'Open the yacht type list to read from it.

        'TODO: Customize the application's assembly information in the "Application" pane of the project 
        '  properties dialog (under the "Project" menu).

        'Application title
        Dim YachtTypeString As String = "YachtTypes.txt"

        Try
            'Open the file.
            Dim YachtsListStreamReader As StreamReader = New StreamReader("YachtTypes.txt")
            ' Read all elements into the list.
            Do Until YachtsListStreamReader.Peek = -1
                YachtTypeString = YachtsListStreamReader.ReadLine()
                KMFile.YachtTypeComboBox.Items.Add(YachtTypeString)
            Loop
            'Close the file.
            YachtsListStreamReader.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            'File missing.
            MessageBox.Show("The yacht types file is not found.", "Enter yacht types manually to save", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        End Try

        If My.Application.Info.Title <> "" Then
            ApplicationTitle.Text = My.Application.Info.Title
        Else
            'If the application title is missing, use the application name, without the extension
            ApplicationTitle.Text = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(My.Application.Info.AssemblyName)
        End If

        'Format the version information using the text set into the Version control at design time as the
        '  formatting string.  This allows for effective localization if desired.
        '  Build and revision information could be included by using the following code and changing the 
        '  Version control's designtime text to "Version {0}.{1:00}.{2}.{3}" or something similar.  See
        '  String.Format() in Help for more information.
        '
        '    Version.Text = System.String.Format(Version.Text, My.Application.Info.Version.Major, My.Application.Info.Version.Minor, My.Application.Info.Version.Build, My.Application.Info.Version.Revision)

        Version.Text = System.String.Format(Version.Text, My.Application.Info.Version.Major, My.Application.Info.Version.Minor)

        'Copyright info
        Copyright.Text = My.Application.Info.Copyright
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, what is the failure?

Comment: It also appears that you are just reading in every line.  Have you considered using File.ReadAllLines("YachtTypes.txt")?

Comment: Why must it be in the Splash screen?  That is unusual.  The Splash Screen should not really be doing any processing other than showing the splash screen!  Where is KMFile?  Is that another form?  It seems so, since it has a combo box.  That form is where you should be reading this file.

Comment: Put the `FullPath` of your file not just the name... **ONLY** if this file doesn't exist in the executable directory...

Comment: The failure is that YachtTypeComboBox simply stays blank, even though the text file exists and the program works to write to it. It throws no exception, so changing the exception code doesn't help. Putting the full path of the file doesn't work either (that is, it doesn't change the result in any way).

Comment: @Beroli: So, when you set a break point at the start of the file reading code and step through your code, what do you observe? How often is the loop executed? Are the variable values what you expect?

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
Catch ex As Exception
    'File missing.
    MessageBox.Show("The yacht types file is not found.", "Enter yacht types manually to save", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
End Try
```

you swallow *all* exceptions and show a generic error message. Don't do that. Include `ex.Message` in your displayed message or *only* catch `FileNotFoundExceptions`s.

That way, you will see the *real* error message, leading you to the *real* cause of the problem you are experiencing.